# Optimizing a function for the number of repetitions of two values in a range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

As the title says. I'm trying to find a faster function (or script function) that will count the number of repetitions in the range (more in TEST SHEET).

Here is what I got as of now:

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(A2)=FALSE;ISBLANK(B2)=FALSE); (LEN(CONCATENATE($E$2:$K$12))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE(TRANSPOSE($E$2:$K$12));A2&B2;"")))/LEN(A2&B2);)
```

**Sheet**

[TEST SHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vb_EpiirpX7AYhHhNFVPxd0EPWnBN4NKw6qSTxGirAQ/edit?usp=sharing)

**Picture**

[image]

For anyone asking why I need it to be faster, I have 720 of these functions and currently 280 are running (the rest have empty cells). Creates little delay/lag (no loading bar) when working with the sheet.

**EDIT**

- Change link to new sheet thanks to "The Master"
- Added new examples
- Added picture

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing [links like spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or [images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data, as they're hard to copy from. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: Thanks for info. I dont realy care about this email. Its kinda burn out email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet. And, please set `searchTextRange`, `srcValueRange`, and your sheet name. And save the script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const searchTextRange = "A2:B8"; // This is from your provided Spreadsheet.
  const srcValueRange = "E2:K12" // This is from your provided Spreadsheet.
  const sheetName = "List 20"; // This is from your provided Spreadsheet.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange(searchTextRange);
  const searchTextValues = range.getDisplayValues();
  const srcValue = sheet.getRange(srcValueRange).getDisplayValues();
  const updateValues = [...Array(Math.ceil(srcValue.length / 3))].flatMap(_ => {
    const [a, b] = srcValue.splice(0, 3).slice(0, 2);
    return a.map((e, i) => `${e}${b[i]}`);
  });
  const res = searchTextValues.map(r => r.join("")).map(e => [e ? updateValues.filter(f => f == e).length : null]);
  range.offset(0, 2, res.length, 1).setValues(res);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run to your provided Spreadsheet, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- If you want to use this script as a custom function, you can use the following sample script. In this case, please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE(A2:B8;E2:K12)` into a cell of "List 20" sheet.

  ```js
  function SAMPLE(searchTextValues, srcValue) {
    const updateValues = [...Array(Math.ceil(srcValue.length / 3))].flatMap(_ => {
      const [a, b] = srcValue.splice(0, 3).slice(0, 2);
      return a.map((e, i) => `${e}${b[i]}`);
    });
    return searchTextValues.map(r => r.join("")).map(e => [e ? updateValues.filter(f => f == e).length : null]);
  }
  ```
- This sample script is for your provided Spreadsheet. When you change the Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

### 2nd question:

About your following new question,

> This function basically solved my main problem. One more thing. Is there a way to change it so that it only returns one result and can accept input from non-adjacent cells. For example, I have one value in cell $E$26 and another value in cell B26. I tryed to change the scrip, but it didnt workout... Added the exemple to sheet.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script 1:

In this sample script, `searchTextRange1`, `searchTextRange2`, `srcValueRange` and `sheetName` are from your new provided Spreadsheet. Please be careful about this.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const searchTextRange1 = "E26"; // This is from your provided Spreadsheet.
  const searchTextRange2 = "B26:30"; // This is from your provided Spreadsheet.
  const srcValueRange = "E2:K12" // This is from your provided Spreadsheet.
  const sheetName = "Build Sample Here"; // This is from your provided Spreadsheet.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const searchTextValues1 = sheet.getRange(searchTextRange1).getDisplayValue();
  const range = sheet.getRange(searchTextRange2);
  const searchTextValues = range.getDisplayValues().map(([e]) => [searchTextValues1, e]);
  const srcValue = sheet.getRange(srcValueRange).getDisplayValues();
  const updateValues = [...Array(Math.ceil(srcValue.length / 3))].flatMap(_ => {
    const [a, b] = srcValue.splice(0, 3).slice(0, 2);
    return a.map((e, i) => `${e}${b[i]}`);
  });
  const res = searchTextValues.map(r => r.join("")).map(e => [e ? updateValues.filter(f => f == e).length : null]);
  range.offset(0, 1, res.length, 1).setValues(res);
}
```

#### Sample script 2:

When your new provided Spreadsheet is used, please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE(E26,B26:30,E2:K12)` into a cell of "Build Sample Here" sheet.

```js
function SAMPLE(searchTextValues1, searchTextValues2, srcValue) {
  searchTextValues = Array.isArray(searchTextValues2) ? searchTextValues2.map(([e]) => [searchTextValues1, e]) : [[searchTextValues1, searchTextValues2]];
  const updateValues = [...Array(Math.ceil(srcValue.length / 3))].flatMap(_ => {
    const [a, b] = srcValue.splice(0, 3).slice(0, 2);
    return a.map((e, i) => `${e}${b[i]}`);
  });
  return searchTextValues.map(r => r.join("")).map(e => [e ? updateValues.filter(f => f == e).length : null]);
}
```

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your new provided Spreadsheet. When you change the Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

Comment: This function basically solved my main problem. One more thing. Is there a way to change it so that it only returns one result and can accept input from non-adjacent cells. For example, I have one value in cell $E$26 and another value in cell B26.
I tryed to change the scrip, but it didnt workout...
Added the exemple to sheet.

Comment: @Dark Thank you for replying. From `This function basically solved my main problem.`, I understood that your question was resolved. About your new question of `One more thing. Is there a way to change it so that it only returns one result and can accept input from non-adjacent cells.`, I added an answer to your 2nd question. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your 2nd question, I apologize.

Comment: So it works for example 1 but not for example 2. I tried changing the first line to this: "searchTextValues = [searchTextValues1, searchTextValues2];" , but it gives an error on join function. Probably because it's no longer a range?

Comment: @Dark Thank you for replying. About `but not for example 2. I tried changing the first line to this: "searchTextValues = [searchTextValues1, searchTextValues2];" , but it gives an error on join function. Probably because it's no longer a range?`, I modified it. Please confirm it.

Comment: So I added another array check and it works as intended ("searchTextValues = Array.isArray(searchTextValues1) ? searchTextValues1.map(([e]) => [e,searchTextValues2]) : Array.isArray(searchTextValues2) ? searchTextValues2.map(([e]) => [searchTextValues1, e]):[[searchTextValues1, searchTextValues2]];"). Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Dark Thank you for replying. I'm glad your both questions were resolved.

Comment: Quick question. How can I reference row in the map function? Right now it only takes first collum (array).

Comment: @Dark About your 3rd question of `Quick question. How can I reference row in the map function? Right now it only takes first collum (array).`, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my very poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand what you want to do in your 3rd question. I have already resolved your 2 questions. But, I cannot understand your 3rd question. When I could correctly understand your 3rd question, I would like to think of a solution. I deeply apologize for my very poor English skill again.

Comment: I am trying to use the values that are in the row. For example - A29:D29.
I tried passing the values like this:
    const test = range.getValues()[0];
    const searchTextValues = test.map(([e]) => [searchTextValues1, e]);
Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: @Dark Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your 3rd question. I deeply apologize for my very poor English skill again. But, I would like to support you. So, in this case, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your 3rd question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
function reps(vs = [1,2], a1rg="Sheet0!A2:P22") {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let n = vs.reduce((a, v) => {
    a += ss.getRange(a1rg).createTextFinder(v).matchEntireCell(true).findAll().length;
    return a;
  }, 0)
  Logger.log(n)
}
```